# non full screen activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fullscreen, touch-event

I want to create a button which will be shown on top of all apps.
[something like this](https://lh3.ggpht.com/mbQb1IrEDepiZb6OaAHt6vqGG96U12uuC_PUp8cGUEK_SUWZxSEhFDuvdmJWkzD8Kg)

as you can see, there is a button at top left corner. it can receive touch events and touch events can be received outside it by other apps.

I tried to use `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` to my activity but it does not helped. I also set size to my button to [100, 100] but other activity behind it can not receive touch events. I think that the problem is in activity's window. it's size does not equel activity's size.
any help please

**UPD**

solved

Comment: mParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hatcyl in [`Create a UI or a widget that sees on top of all Application in Android?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498366/create-a-ui-or-a-widget-that-sees-on-top-of-all-application-in-android) says:

> If you want something to be clickable, you can display it on top of
>   anything except the lockscreen.

You would to use a `service` and `WindowManager` to show a button on every App.