# Android - detect gesture across entire device

Tags: android, background

I found some methods to launch an application by putting button on top of entire device. This should be available even if the application is not in main activity.

- [Gesture Listener across entire device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975865/gesture-listener-across-entire-device)
- [Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top)

I wanna do little a different **launch an application by specific gestures**, (e.g. swipe gesture starting from bezel) without putting layouts or buttons on top of screen.

Is there any suggestions?