# showing image on top of running phone

Tags: android

how is it possible to show an image ontop of a running activity while still being able to control the background?
in case some ppl say it is not possible, check this app out:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myboyfriendisageek.stickit&hl=en

is there a way to open a transparent activity but still being able to control the previous activity?
ive also tried using a toast, but that is capped by a timer, and i have not been able to find a way to control it.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498366/create-a-ui-or-a-widget-that-sees-on-top-of-all-application-in-android

Comment: this is exactly what i needed. but for some reason i cant get it to work. once i add the wm.addview(ll,ll_p); it gives an error

Comment: in the post they have not initialized the windowmanager, Maybe that is why you are getting error. have you initialized wm